# SQL Statement : Update issue

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I have these three tables :

```
RESEARCHER(Re_Id, Re_Name, Re_Address, Re_Phone, Re_HomePhoneNumber,
Re_OfficeNumber, Re_FirstScore, Re_Second_Score)

PUBLICATION(Pub_ID, Pub_Title, Pub_Type, Pub_Publisher, Pub_Year,Pub_Country, Pub_StartingPage, Pub_Number_of_Page, Score1, Score2)

WRITTEN_BY(Re_Id, Pub_ID)
```

I want to change the authors of the publication “*Introduction to Database System*” to *“Henry Gordon”* and *“Sarah Parker”*.

The problem is in **WRITTEN_BY** table,I just store the **researcher's ID** and **publication's ID**.

My idea is to change the **Re_Id** in **WRITTEN_BY** by those names are "*Henry Gorgon*" , "*Sarah Parker*" , which are already existed in **RESEARCHER** table

```
UPDATE WRITTEN_BY
SET Re_Id = ....( SELECT Re_Id
                  FROM RESEACHER
                  WHERE Re_Name = ‘Henry Gordon’ OR Re_Name = ‘Sarah Paker’ )
WHERE Pub_ID IN ( SELECT Pub_ID
                   FROM PUBLICATION
                   WHERE Pub_Name = ‘Introduciton to Database system’ );
```

I have problem in the SET part,so how to write the SQL statement for that requirement? 
Here is the sqlfiddle link for my schema : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9118/1

Comment: @DươngAnhKhoa I've put up an answer using SQL Server logic. Even though your DB is Oracle, same logic will work as `CROSS JOIN` is same in Oracle and SQL server

Comment: @DươngAnhKhoa If i run your fiddle with oracle DB i get an `ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: @Jens just run MySQL,I dont know why oracle DB doesnt work

Comment: But mysql and oracle are very different in such thinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use something like below query:

```
DELETE FROM WRITTEN_BY WHERE Pub_ID IN (
SELECT Pub_ID FROM PUBLICATION
                   WHERE Pub_Title = 'Introduciton to Database system' )

INSERT INTO WRITTEN_BY 
SELECT Re_Id,Pub_Id
FROM RESEARCHER CROSS JOIN PUBLICATION 
WHERE Re_Name = 'Henry Gordon' OR Re_Name = 'Sarah Paker' 
AND Pub_Title like 'Introduciton to Database system'

SELECT * FROM WRITTEN_BY
```

The idea is to first drop the existing mapping- you should not update it- and the insert a new one.

The reason for delete/insert approach vs update in case of mapping table is justified in favor of delete/insert as most mapping tables contain many-many mapping and usually one-to-many mappings.

Initially we may have a book mapped to say n number of authors where n <>1 then we either add extra rows, or are left with extraneous rows.

See sample fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0e72/13

The real deal however is `CROSS JOIN`. This does not take any `ON`  like other `JOIN`s and is used to produce cartesian product type map. 
We are restricting it to get only limited number of rows as per our need by adding suitable `WHERE` clauses

Comment: It did work. In your fiddle link posted in comment note the typo in name of researcher here `OR Re_Name = 'Sarah Paker' `. This should be `Parker` and not `Paker`

Comment: There were some more typos in your query. Look out for the spelling of `Introduction`. I corrected it and here's how it looks like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbeb8/3

Comment: That is because you used MySQL instead of SQL server in this fiddle. mySql requires the following part to be written like this `INSERT INTO WRITTEN_BY 
SELECT Re_Id,Pub_Id
FROM RESEARCHER CROSS JOIN PUBLICATION 
WHERE (Re_Name = 'Henry Gordon' OR Re_Name = 'Sarah Parker' )
AND Pub_Title like 'Introduction to Database System'`. Note the parenthesis around the Re_Name OR clause.